# Angular exchanging acces token for bearer's token Oauth2

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I need to exchange my authorization code for bearer's token in Google Api Service. There is a nice application called [OauthPlayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) that describes Oauth2 flow. For tokens exchange it uses request like this:

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 233
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground

code=4%2F6RMgcR3WKuY8_bIaZa0o8P6xfxMKZh1f6AZmh9Q-h6Y&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=************&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
```

I have registered my application at [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/) and have my own client_id and client_secret. My code that doesn't works is below:

```
tryGetBearers(){
    let connString='www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
    let connBody='code='+this.accessToken;
    connBody+='&redirect_uri='+this.redirect_uri
    connBody+='&client_id='+this.client_id
    connBody+='&client_secret='+this.client_secret
    connBody+='&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code'

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    this.http.post(connString,connBody,{headers:headers}).subscribe(
      res=>{console.log(res);},
      (error)=>{console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

The example body sent with request is:

```
code=4/Q5p52c8zMfwzAKErog-7QUJzv7aYGyAlCDz_5KE0Mgw&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200&client_id=665991054229-jmd9i1ovcohglkrlbu1ff1nih9j1cqia.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=hnrh1eGPKFmdEWkdWna7zs6K&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The response of the function is just 404 Not Found. I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the url is bad. Instead of

```
let connString='www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
```

Using this is ok:

```
let connString='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
```